# changing sharepoint trust on application page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Good day.

So ive been reading on how it is bad "practice" to set a SharePoint applications trust to full. Due to this hackers are able to infiltrate you web app. what if though there are pages or web parts that require full trust to function correctly?!

In my case i want to elevate the trust on a coded application page and maybe a custom web part. Are there any ideas on how one would go about doing that in code?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Fix the broken pages and the web parts so they don't require elevated priviledges. WHY do you require evelated priviledges? Remember, a SharePoint site isn't a simple web site, it isn't your own, it isn't deployed on your servers and whoever manages the farm will be very VERY annoyed if you ask him to fiddle with configurations across the farm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()` method to run any code in your application page with elevated privileges for unprivileged user

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
    // implementation details omitted
    }
});
```

It is important to create new SPSite object and SPWeb object inside delegate. Do not reuse existing SPSite object and SPWeb object because they are created with restricted permissions

Comment: Thanks, i was questioning the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges and how it should be implemented, but you clarified it for me